# How to get rid of the extra blank pages in PDF version of SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I tried creating a report using a sub report. When I exported it to PDF I have noticed that there are extra blank pages in the PDF.
I made it clear that body `width + left margin+ right margin <= report width`.
But still it gives the blank page. sub report as individual working great.

Also I am calling the sub report from with in a list  in main report.
I tried to set up a page break after list . but it looks like its not working.

I want the next list displayed on a new page.

How do I achieve these.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single property available for this in SSRS. You have to check for couple of settings

1. In report properties, set **"ConsumeContainerWhitespace"** to TRUE
2. In tablix properties, set page braek location to NONE
3. IF still the issue persists, check alignment/margin of objects like rectangle,tablix etc.

Comment: THANK YOU! That did the trick for me.  Dang was that annoying!

Answer (score 2):

A few things to look for:

- Check the "parent" and subreport for any controls that are in your margins (or may grow into the margins). Setting the width doesn't necessarily force the controls to that width.
- check for any controls that overlap. I've had strange things happen because of that (especially in SSRS 2005).
- checking the "Print Layout" while previewing helps find most issues like this at design time (before exporting to PDF).
- For the hard break with your list not sure what is goofy there. I usually use a table with groups and set the page breaks on the appropriate group. Depends on the data though.

  HTH

Answer (score 1):

Check top and Bottom margins, for me reducing.1 of bottom margin solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (with Report Builder 2017) the solution to get rid of a blank extra-page was to reduce the width of the body.

The body can be selected by clicking on a free space in the report on the same height than the Tablix is located.

You then get the "Body properties" shown in which you can reduce the size.

The size of the body should be less than `page width - left margin - right margin`.

[image: Report Builder body properties]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with the sub report's width which caused extra blank pages in the exported version. Reducing the width solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If still someone having an issue with blank pages in PDF, just increase the width of the main report to a few inches. Keep reducing to an optimum value by checking the report. No need to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For me when I increase the width for pagesize report from 21 to 23 cm,

> It was not generating extra empty page. Because of few elements total
> size of my report's element was greater than 21 and less than 23, that
> is why I changed to 23cm and works for me.

In my case I have only one page and I was working with .rdl file.

Answer (score -1):

When exporting to pdf and the report contains a sub report where the sub report is grouped on an item from parent report.

Do not use the list control in the parent report to group sub report. Use the table control.

The list control will cause blank pages while the table control does not